# Laravel factory and selected a unique belongsTo instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, factory

I have a `hasOne` relationship in that a `Campaign` `hasOne` `Product`

The `Product` `belongsTo` the `Campaign`.

In this particular case, in the `products` database table, there should only ever be one, unique reference to a `campaign`. I set the constraint on the database side to `unique`. My question is, when defining a factory, how do I ensure that it picks a unique Campaign, which was previously created by a seeder?

```
class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
   
    protected $model = Product::class;

   
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //
            'name'        => $this->faker->sentence,
            'description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
            'campaign_id' => Campaign::inRandomOrder()->first()->id, # this won't work
        ];
    }
```

It is obvious why `Campaign::inRandomOrder()->first()->id` won't work. I don't necessarily want to use a Campaign factory here to create a new Campaign either because there's a lot of nuances in how each instance is created and I already take care of that in my `CampaignSeeder`

I am interested in just associating each Product created with a `Campaign` that has yet to be claimed when I seed. What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a relationship **product** in your **campaign model**

```
class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
   
    protected $model = Product::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //
            'name'        => $this->faker->sentence,
            'description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
            'campaign_id' => Campaign::doesntHave('product')->first()->id, 
        ];
    }
```

everytime it will get first campaign in your table that doesnt have a product

Comment: you're welcome, you can find others you might need in future in laravel docs :
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships